# Como Buscar valor anterior da variavel PHP

Tags: php, variáveis

Tenho uma variável que tem o valor de *arroz*, logo depois de receber o valor de *arroz*, ela recebe o valor *feijao*. Como eu chamo o valor passado da função? Segue exemplo a baixo:

```
$arroz = "arroz";

echo $arroz; = arroz

$arroz = "feijao";

echo $arroz; = feijao

echo $arroz-valor-passado = "arroz";
```

Comment: Pelo que conheço do PHP não podes fazer isso. Só se mantiveres o valor passado noutra variável ou um *array* de valores passados.

Comment: Eu não entendi essa linha `echo $arroz-valor-passado = "arroz";`. No mais, o uso de um *array* pode ser a melhor escolha como disse @JorgeB.

Comment: @PapaCharlie quando ela faz echo põe o resultado esperado a frente com o `= resultado`

Comment: @JorgeB., isso entendi, poderia ter usado `//`, mas o que não entendi foi `$arroz-valor-passado`. É uma nova variável inexistente?

Comment: @PapaCharlie é isso. Era como ela queria que fosse...

Comment: @JorgeB., não tinha entendido se era uma nova var ou *$arroz (subtração) valor-passado* - ficou confuso. Poderia fazer algo usando `extract`, dependendo do uso da var. Seria melhor saber a aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Isso não é possivel numa variável.

A solução que sugiro é teres uma array. Assim vais acumulando valores dentro dela e usas o `count($array) - 1` para ir buscar o ultimo valor que foi inserido na array. E os valores anteriores seguindo a mesma lógica. Algo como isto:

```
$comida = array();
$comida[] = "arroz";
echo $comida[count(comida) - 1];    // arroz

$comida[] = "feijão";
echo $comida[(count($comida) - 1)]; // feijão
echo $comida[count($comida) - 2];   // arroz
```